# How do I connect a bathroom fan to existing switches?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, exhaust-fan

I have 6 wires. One white one black and one ground from each bundle of 3. I need to power a vent fan that requires 1 ground 1 white and 1 black. The grounds are easy as they get pigtailed together. My problem is figuring out how to connect the others. When I connect all whites together and all blacks together the fan runs but isn’t able to be turned off by the switch. I need it to turn off when I flip the switch.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One cable in the box should be power and the other one goes to the switch.

The black and white(should have black tape on it) going to the switch can be thought of one wire(hot and switch hot).

Surprise that when you connected blacks to blacks/whites to whites the breaker did not trip.

Find the black hot live wire connect to white going to switch(with black tape), black from switch to black fan wire.  White fan wire connects to white wire on the power/live cable, not from the switch.

Should move the wires on that switch from the push-ins to the screws.  Push-ins are not as good as the screws for connection.

Comment: Thank you. This actually makes sense to me now. I don’t have a tester but I have the ability to figure out which one is the hot and which one is the switch. I will try this as soon as I can.